# Why does my <input> element's content area go outside of its parent <span> element?

Tags: html, css, margin, box-sizing

**Note:** Since I have been trying to extract the code from a wordpress environment Salient theme, I have not been able to reproduce the issue in it's simplest form yet, I may end up answering my own question but please be aware that I appreciate any feedback along the way and I hope this question will be informative to the community.

My issue thus far is decribed below:

---

I am trying to gain better control over the way my content is displayed on the screen and there appear to be something I'm not understanding about CSS. I have tried using the "box-sizing: border box" property which includes padding and borders in the calculation of the total width of an element. I have added links to show the state of the input and span elements

["Chrome Devtool" Input element highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qMTR.png)

["Chrome Devtool" Span element content area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4peU9.png)

I assume box-sizing doesn't work because the issue is a margin related issue. My best guess is that the "margin-left" property has affected the total content area, pushing the content outside of the span element. However I want the input element to be contained inside the span element

**HTML and CSS addition with thanks from Lucien Dubois**

```css
* { 
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.contact-fields input, textarea{
  margin-left: 12px;
}
 
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
  display: block !important;
  position: relative;
}

div, span, h5, p {
  vertical-align: baseline; 
  font-family: inherit; 
  font-weight: inherit; 
  font-style: inherit; 
  font-size: 100%; 
  outline: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin-right: 0; 
  border: 0
}

h5
{
 font-family:Raleway;
 line-height:16px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 color:#444; 
 letter-spacing:0px;
 font-weight:600;
}

.form-label {
  clear: both;
  font-size: 20px
}

h5 {
  vertical-align: baseline; 
  font-style: inherit; 
  outline: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border:0
}

.first-name,  .last-name {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 9px;
}

.first-name input, .last-name input {
  width: 62%;
}

input {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-fields">
  <div class="name-section">
    <div class="first-name">
      <h5 class="form-label"> First Name:</h5>
      <p>      
         <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap fname">
           <input type="text" 
                  name="fname" 
                  value="" 
                  size="40" 
                  maxlength="50" 
                  class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required input-field" 
                  aria-required="true" 
                  aria-invalid="false">
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="last-name">
      <h5 class="form-label"> Surname:</h5>
        <p>      
          <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap lname">
            <input type="text" 
                   name="lname" 
                   value="" 
                   size="40" 
                   maxlength="50" 
                   class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required input-field" 
                   aria-required="true" 
                   aria-invalid="false"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share code snippets and not images for Stackoverflow users to help you.

Comment: With all due respect I do believe the images were necessary to show the graphical issue I was facing, however I do believe you are correct in that I should have supplied the CSS and HTML code alongside the images

Comment: Try to use div instead of span.

Comment: gives the same result Jobz.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by adding min and max properties for your input field

```
input {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```